# Flutter how to right align last column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter, how do I make the third column fill the width? I'm trying to right-align the edit icon.

```
Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [ SizedBox(width: 10) ]
        ),
        Column(
          children: [ Text("example") ]
        ),
        Column(
          children: [ IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit)) ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

All of the things I've tried such as putting it in `Expanded()` or `IntrinsicWidth()` or `Column(..., crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch)` have resulted in "Cannot hit test a render box that has never been laid out."

Answer (score 1):

Place `Spacer()` before last `Column`.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your column with `Align` and then `Expanded` and then set `Alignment:Alignment.centerRight`
. this will give you the flexibility to place your widget any place you want.
see [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) from Flutter Docs.

```
Row(
              children: [
                Column(children: [SizedBox(width: 10)]),
                Column(children: [Text("example")]),
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```